# Prevent MTKView camera feed rotation, but allow other on-screen VCs to rotate

Tags: ios, swift, metal, core-image, avcam

### Goal

With an MTKView, replicate the gravity of the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer or Apple's Camera app.  Video device orientation does not change. The camera feed's edges do not budge a pixel, never revealing the screen background. Other on-screen VCs rotate normally.

### Observed

Applying [Tech QA 1890's transform](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1890/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015222) during `viewWillTransition`, the `MTKView` does counter-rotate... BUT that rotation is still uncomfortably visible. The edges of the view come unpinned during the animation, masking some camera pixels and showing a white background set for the VC holding the MTKView.

[image: edges visible during rotation]

### Question

How can I make those edges stick to screen bounds like a scared clam?

I assume my error is in constraints, but I'm open to being wrong in other ways. :)

### View Hierarchy

A tiny camera filter app has an overlay of camera controls (VC #1) atop an MTKView (in VC #2) pinned to the screen's edges.

```swift
UINavigationController
│ 
└─ CameraScreenVC
   │    
   ├── CameraControlsVC    <- Please rotate subviews
   │ 
   └── MetalCameraFeedVC
       └── MTKView         <- Please no rotation edges
```

### Code

[Buildable demo repo](https://github.com/importRyan/RotationDemo/blob/main/WCAG%20Shades/Presentation/CameraScreen/CameraViewController/MetalCameraVC%2BRotation.swift)

Relevant snippets below.

**MetalCameraVC.swift**

```swift
final class MetalCameraVC: UIViewController {

    let mtkView = MTKView()    // This VC's only view

    /// Called in viewDidAppear
    func setupMetal(){
        metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        mtkView.device = metalDevice
        mtkView.isPaused = true
        mtkView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = false
        metalCommandQueue = metalDevice.makeCommandQueue()
        mtkView.delegate = self
        mtkView.framebufferOnly = false
        ciContext = CIContext(
            mtlDevice: metalDevice,
            options: [.workingColorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!])
    }

    ...

    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) { 
         // blank 
    }

    func draw(in mtkview: MTKView) {
        
        image = image.transformed(by: scaleToScreenBounds)
        image = image.cropped(to: mtkview.drawableSize.zeroOriginRect())

        guard let buffer = metalCommandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(),
              let currentDrawable = mtkview.currentDrawable
        else { return }
        
        ciContext.render(image,
                         to: currentDrawable.texture,
                         commandBuffer: buffer,
                         bounds: mtkview.drawableSize.zeroOriginRect(),
                         colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())
        
        buffer.present(currentDrawable)
        buffer.commit()
    }
}

extension MetalCameraVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(mtkView)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        mtkView.frame = view.frame

        if let orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.fromCurrentDeviceOrientation() {
            lastOrientation = orientation
        }
    }
}
```

**+Rotation**

```swift
/// Apple Technical QA 1890 Prevent View From Rotating
extension MetalCameraVC {
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        mtkView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        coordinator.animate { [self] context in

            let delta = coordinator.targetTransform
            let deltaAngle = atan2(delta.b, delta.a)
            var currentAngle = mtkView.layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z") as? CGFloat ?? 0
            currentAngle += -1 * deltaAngle + 0.1
            mtkView.layer.setValue(currentAngle, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z")

        } completion: { [self] context in

            var rounded = mtkView.transform
            rounded.a = round(rounded.a)
            rounded.b = round(rounded.b)
            rounded.c = round(rounded.c)
            rounded.d = round(rounded.d)
            mtkView.transform = rounded
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the "easiest" solution is to actually *prevent* your UI from rotating and observing device orientation changes to manually rotate only the interface elements you want to rotate.

In your view controller, you can override `shouldAutorotate` to prevent auto-rotation and use `supportedInterfaceOrientations` to only return the one allowed orientation.

Rotating UI elements manually can be done using their `transform` property.

Comment: Hah, in frustration, I did exactly that on the Nav controller (which is the determinant I think for everyone). I prefer that UI... except context menus come up 90* off. :( An Apple engineer suggested the same thing in a lab last week, but said don't tell anyone about it. :)